# Do the Weasley twins know that Sirius, Lupin, James and Peter are the Marauders?

Tags: harry-potter

After they become acquainted with Remus and Sirius, do Fred and George figure out that they are Moony and Padfoot, respectively? After that, I would assume they would connect James and Peter.

Comment: I'll have to check but I don't think there's canon confirmation. But presumably, Ron could have told them - I don't recall the Trio taking a vow to keep silent about details of how events of PoA ended aside from time-turners.

Comment: For the love of Merlin's beard, Fred and George didn't even notice that someone named Peter Pettigrew was sleeping in their brother Ron's bed every night (and before that, with Percy)! I do not think they knew the  identities of the Marauders, but agree with the answer that says they likely respected Sirius and Remus as Order members. They probably knew little about James, and even less about Pettigrew. My $0.02! :)

Comment: @Slytherincess - Presumably, the marauder's map was a map of HOGWARTS and it's secrets. I very much doubt that it was a magical map of whatever residence you happened to have the map in. The only place they might have noticed was if Percy had Scabbers/Pettigrew with him at Hogwarts (IIRC, Percy got an own when he was made head boy, but not 100% sure on that).

Comment: @Slytherincess: Maybe Fred and George, as supporting brothers they were, didn't want to question Ron's and Percy's tendencies.

Comment: I was always puzzled how they worked out how to use it!

Answer (score 5):

It's never stated in-canon that they're aware of their status as the Marauders, but nonetheless, we can deduce that that they respect them as members of the Order and as extended *de facto* family.

Comment: I think they respected Remus and Sirius for sure. James was dead and the twins never got to know him, so I would imagine they respected more the lore surrounding James. I can't imagine them having any respect for Peter. I know the question asks about Remus and Sirius specifically, but I thought I'd throw that in there. :)

Answer (score 1):

It seems like they would, but I don't think they ever find out.

Plus, according to the [Harry Potter Wikia article on Fred Weasley](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Fred_Weasley):

> Fred and his brother George regarded the Marauders with a kind of idolatry... The twins did not, however, work out that two of the Marauders were two of their friends in the Order of the Phoenix: Remus Lupin and Sirius Black. Neither did they discover that Prongs was in fact Harry's father, James, and that Wormtail was actually Death Eater Peter Pettigrew."

And the HP Wiki is usually correct with Canon.

Comment: Could you add a link to your source please?

Comment: -1 specifically for the last line.. HP Wiki is frequently either wrong about canon, or writes facts to "explain" canon that aren't canon supported.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe they did at the time they had the map, since A) there would have been no way (or reason) of knowing enough details of those people's pasts, and B) I don't feel like they would have been too interested in finding out who it was, more just in using the Map. However, later on after Harry and the others know, and especially after the OotP is reestablished, they may have found out.

Comment: Do you have any support for this, or is it just a guess?

Comment: As far as I know it never says one way or another in canon, it just seems like a logical conclusion.